# как проверить на ошибку используя if

Tags: c++

У меня есть код который использует try catch мне надо его отключить и заменить обычным if условием на проверку ошибок.
пытаюсь сделать так но не работает.

```
if (fs.open(file, fstream::out | ios::binary) != 0) {
  cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

Пишет в консоль
ошибка  C2120    "void" недопустимо для всех типов

Странно а с этим работает нормально

```
if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) != 0) {
 cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Приведите объявление `fs` и `file`.

Comment: @maestro смысли как обычно вызываться fstream fs; 
внутри file = файл

Comment: @Abyx Хочу проверить сработало или нет.
Я как считаю если 0 значит ошибок нету если что то другое значит ошибка

Comment: Я понимаю что неправильно проверяю, вопрос как мне правильно проверить.

Comment: `fs.is_open()` ?

Comment: мне нужно так же инициализировать запуск, что если во время запуска будет ошибка и он пройдет мимо.

Comment: Ну так я и хочу поймать исключения через if
так не работает
if (fs.open(file, fstream::out | ios::binary) != fs.is_open())

а такой не подходит надо же запустить
if (!fs.is_open())
                {}

Comment: Да это понятно но мне надо узнать как ловить через if или вы считаете что все пользуются только try catch, надо найти другой способ :)

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле немного сложнее я просто наверно неверно его описал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/basic_ios/rdstate/

```
// getting the state of stream objects
#include <iostream>     // std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is;
  is.open ("test.txt");
  if ( (is.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit ) != 0 )
    std::cerr << "Error opening 'test.txt'\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Есть другой вариант где инициализация идет а потом проверка и все это в одном?
хотя стоп, секунду сейчас потестирую

Comment: заверните пример в `static inline` и все дела.

Comment: пока еще не понял как это работает особенно .rdstate :)

Comment: Как то все сложно я правильно понимаю что is.open это запуск а где if эта уже проверка запуска?

Comment: `rdstate` - возвращает биты состояния потока. `&` - битная операция проверки бита номер `failbit`.

Comment: получается вместо одного if мне надо сделать два условия, в принципе этот вариант возможно подойдет, сейчас разберусь.

Comment: Я сначало не понял но этот вариант оказался правильным :)

Comment: А как добавить еще проверку на badbit, так будет правильно? if ((fs.rdstate() & fstream::failbit & fstream::badbit) или там нужно использовать |

Comment: два разных бита `failbit` и `badbit` нельзя сравнивать друг с другом. Будет ноль. Правильнее так : `(состояние & failbit) || (состояние & badbit)`

Comment: Понял, а кретично тогда если я не буду использовать badbit?
смысле не крашнит у меня программу, а лучше как мне бы проверить это :D

Answer (score 2):

Метод `open`, не бросает никаких исключений, а проверку на корректное открытие необходимо проверять после попытки открытия, т.е. после вызова метода `open`.

Проверяйте методом [`std::fstream::is_open`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/is_open/).

```
fs.open(file, std::ios::binary);

if(!fs.is_open()) // check for open here
{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file by path: " << file << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А другой вариант есть?, что если continue; кинет вверх и fs.open запустится второй раз, тогда будет фатал ерор)

Comment: Это как относится к заданному вами вопросу?

Comment: Вопрос тот же просто я описал как можно вызвать критическую ошибку с вашим примером, но так ваш вариант правильный.

Comment: Для начала, там не будет никакой критической ошибки, просто вас снова забросит на ветвление `if(!fs.is_open())`. А Что вам мешает прервать цикл или вы этого тоже не умеете?

Comment: А там нельзя прервать цикл он бесконечный, цикл будет работать пока не выполнятся все условия.

Comment: В смысле? Оператор `break` прервет ваш цикл, хоть он бесконечный, хоть нет.

Comment: Я понимаю но этого делать нельзя